# Как сделать, чтобы сайт понимал и .jpg и .JPG?

Tags: html, .htaccess, веб-программирование

Что нужно сделать, чтобы запись типа:

```
<img src='img.jpg'>
```

cрабатывала и с картинкой "img.jpg" и с "img.JPG"?

Где-то читал, что такое можно сделать через .htaccess, но не помню как.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, чтобы картинка `img.jpg` отдавалась на запрос `img.JPG`? Попробуйте `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что везде в коде, расширение пишется маленькими буквами. А расширение файлов на сервере может именоваться большими буквами.

Comment: Ну, `RewriteRule` должно подойти и для этого случая. Можно поюзать `mod_spelling` с CheckCaseOnly. ([ссылка](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_speling.html)) Но я бы заставил клиентов указывать правильный адрес в любом случае, а все расширения на сервере скорректировал в lowercase.